# Why do PowerPivots with multiple sources not show the correct data unless something is added to the Values list?

Tags: excel, powerpivot, powerbi

I have three tables:

Person

[image]

Event

[image]

PersonEvent

[image]

Persons attend Events. This many-to-many relationship is modeled by the junction table PersonEvent, which also records Hours Spent on the Event. I added each of these tables to the Data Model, which looks like this:

[image]

I want to see which Persons attended which Events. The PowerPivot shows every Person as attending every Event, which is obviously wrong:

[image]

Only when I add the Sum of Hours Spent to the PowerPivot does the correct information display:

[image]

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Power Pivot and everything to do with Excel pivot table MDX generation.

[Here's a thorough explanation from a thread I participated in on the Technet forums.](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/956e6a9e-b39d-444e-a26c-23ceac4ed37f/problem-with-relation-when-one-dimension-table-relates-to-another?forum=sqlkjpowerpivotforexcel) See the second-to-last post in the thread.